# Button method error?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I create a view, save the XAML into a file and want to open the file up that I select from a combobox.

```
public MainWindow2(string name)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        cmbnames.Items.Add(name);
        string choice = cmbnames.SelectedItem.ToString();
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e, string choice)
{
        using (var fs = File.Open(choice, FileMode.Open))
        {
            stacky1.Children.Add((UIElement)XamlReader.Load(fs));
        }
}
```

I am trying to select an item from a ComboBox and then when I click load it should find the file and load up that XAML.

But for some reason I get an error saying:

```
No overload for 'Button_Click_1' matches delegate 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `private void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e, string choice)`

Use this

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
```

Comment: I need it to pass `choice` though. I changed to `System.EventArgs` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Najaraj S Thanks for your help I moved the String choice to the button method and didnt pas sit anything.